# No overload matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net

> CS0123: No overload for 'addItems' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

```
// 
// pictureBox1
// 
this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(35)))));
this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-3, -1);
this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(586, 44);
this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 4;
this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
// 
// pictureBox2
//
```

I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and tried what they did but it's still not working. I expected the program to move without the borders and it didn't work

Comment: Have a look at this site https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-delegates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your code from this:

```
this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
```

to:

```
this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += this.pictureBox1_MouseMove;
this.pictureBox1.Click += this.pictureBox1_Click;
```

after that, you can to add to you code something like this:

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
        Operation();
 }
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Operation();
 }
 private void Operation()
 {
    //ENTER YOUR CODE
 }
```

Let me know if this can help you